# What is wrong in my python function?

Tags: python, bash, sorting

My script takes DHCP leases and writes them into a log file.

I can only sort it after the ip and not the date. I take the information from the lease file and save it into a list. So that 1 lease = 1 list element. Because of that I can only sort after the first numbers which is the ip.

So I thought that I could sort it with a bash command, this is my function:

```
def bash_command(cmd):
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")

bash_command("cat log.txt | sort -n -t: -k2,2 > log2.txt")
```

Now if I run my script it generates log.txt and log2.txt but both are sorted with the ip.

Some examples out of the log.txt:

```
lease 129.132.108.230 :starts 2015.06.15 17:15:37: ends 2015.06.15 17:16:02
lease 129.132.108.231 :starts 2015.06.16 15:17:32: ends 2015.06.16 15:17:59
lease 129.132.108.232 :starts 2015.06.24 11:40:41: ends 2015.06.24 12:52:26
lease 129.132.108.233 :starts 2015.06.22 06:52:01: ends 2015.06.22 06:46:31
lease 129.132.108.234 :starts 2015.06.19 12:02:01: ends 2015.06.19 12:00:02
lease 129.132.108.235 :starts 2015.06.18 23:12:36: ends 2015.06.18 23:12:35
```

Edit: I first tried to solve my Problem without Bash.

```
#def extract_date(datetime):
        #   try:
        #       MyList.datetime.datetime.strptime (text.rsplit(None, 1)[-1], "%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S;")
        #       return sorted(MyList)#, key=lambda datetime: datetime[2])
        #   except:
        #       pass
```

This Function was my first try.
And This is how i sort it after the ip atm:

```
if os.path.exists("/home/nraffael/log.txt"):
f=open("log.txt", "a")
sorted(MyList, key=lambda time: time[1])
for ele in sorted(MyList):
    f.write(ele)
```

Comment: You should post also an example of `log.txt`

Comment: Please provide the `log.txt` or at least a part of it so we can test ourselves.  It seems you only have a problem with the correct way of calling `sort`.  The Python part seems not involved.

Comment: it's generally good to avoid shell = True.

call bash_command(['cat','log.txt','|','sort','-n','-t:','-k2',',','2','>','log2.txt']) or something similar, more here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Comment: It would be preferable to convert the time text to python time format using strptime (https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) and then sort,

Comment: Why are you getting Bash to do the sorting, rather than doing it directly in Python?

Comment: The `sorted()` function does **not** modify the original list, it returns a new list. So `sorted(MyList, key=lambda time: time[1])` creates a new list & then throws it away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is sort-only, not Python.  While using a Python-intern solution would probably preferable, your program stands as it is and can easily be corrected.

Just use:

```
sort -t: -k +2
```

instead of

```
sort -n -t: -k2,2
```

You do not need the option `-n` because your dates are properly formatted (even with leading zeros), so normal ASCII sorting will sort them just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much this simple change solved my problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, @n.raffael!  In case an answer solves your problem, you are supposed to "accept" it (check the hook besides it).  If an answer is helpful without directly solving the issue, or solving the issue and helpful otherwise, you can still upvote it (the triangle above the number besides the answer).  If an answer is off-topic, incomplete, plain wrong or otherwise not suitable, you can downvote it (the triangle below the number besides the answer).

Answer (score 1):

From the [`sort`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) man page:

> -n, --numeric-sort          compare according to string numerical value

The fact is that and ip is not a number, so when you use `-n` you are comparing only the number up to the first non-digit character (*the first dot in the ip address*). So you are comparing only the first octet of the ip address.

A way to sort ip addresses with `sort` is the following:

```
sort -n -t . -k 1,1 -k 2,2 -k 3,3 -k 4,4
```

You just have do adapt it in order to also extract the ip address from your string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But What I am trying to achieve is to sort after the starting Date.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to sort your log data in Python, sorting by start date:

```
data = '''
lease 129.132.108.230 :starts 2015.06.15 17:15:37: ends 2015.06.15 17:16:02
lease 129.132.108.231 :starts 2015.06.16 15:17:32: ends 2015.06.16 15:17:59
lease 129.132.108.232 :starts 2015.06.24 11:40:41: ends 2015.06.24 12:52:26
lease 129.132.108.233 :starts 2015.06.22 06:52:01: ends 2015.06.22 06:46:31
lease 129.132.108.234 :starts 2015.06.19 12:02:01: ends 2015.06.19 12:00:02
lease 129.132.108.235 :starts 2015.06.18 23:12:36: ends 2015.06.18 23:12:35
'''.splitlines()[1:]

for row in data:
    print(row)

print('\nSorted by start date')
data.sort(key=lambda row: row.split()[3])

for row in data:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
lease 129.132.108.230 :starts 2015.06.15 17:15:37: ends 2015.06.15 17:16:02
lease 129.132.108.231 :starts 2015.06.16 15:17:32: ends 2015.06.16 15:17:59
lease 129.132.108.232 :starts 2015.06.24 11:40:41: ends 2015.06.24 12:52:26
lease 129.132.108.233 :starts 2015.06.22 06:52:01: ends 2015.06.22 06:46:31
lease 129.132.108.234 :starts 2015.06.19 12:02:01: ends 2015.06.19 12:00:02
lease 129.132.108.235 :starts 2015.06.18 23:12:36: ends 2015.06.18 23:12:35

Sorted by start date
lease 129.132.108.230 :starts 2015.06.15 17:15:37: ends 2015.06.15 17:16:02
lease 129.132.108.231 :starts 2015.06.16 15:17:32: ends 2015.06.16 15:17:59
lease 129.132.108.235 :starts 2015.06.18 23:12:36: ends 2015.06.18 23:12:35
lease 129.132.108.234 :starts 2015.06.19 12:02:01: ends 2015.06.19 12:00:02
lease 129.132.108.233 :starts 2015.06.22 06:52:01: ends 2015.06.22 06:46:31
lease 129.132.108.232 :starts 2015.06.24 11:40:41: ends 2015.06.24 12:52:26
```

To sort by start date and time, just change the `lambda` to

```python
lambda row: row.split()[3:5]
```

We can get away with using simple string comparison here because the subfields in the date and the time fields (i.e., the day, month, hour, minute & second) are zero padded to uniform length.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with python by parsing the start date and time with `datetime.strptime`:

```
lines = """lease 129.132.108.230 :starts 2015.06.15 17:15:37: ends 2015.06.15 17:16:02
lease 129.132.108.231 :starts 2015.06.16 15:17:32: ends 2015.06.16 15:17:59
lease 129.132.108.232 :starts 2015.06.24 11:40:41: ends 2015.06.24 12:52:26
lease 129.132.108.233 :starts 2015.06.22 06:52:01: ends 2015.06.22 06:46:31
lease 129.132.108.234 :starts 2015.06.19 12:02:01: ends 2015.06.19 12:00:02
lease 129.132.108.235 :starts 2015.06.18 23:12:36: ends 2015.06.18 23:12:35"""


from datetime import datetime
def key(x):
    spl = x.split()
    return datetime.strptime("{} {}".format(spl[3],spl[4]),"%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S:")
print(sorted(lines.splitlines(),key=key))
```

Output:

```
['lease 129.132.108.230 :starts 2015.06.15 17:15:37: ends 2015.06.15 17:16:02', 'lease 129.132.108.231 :starts 2015.06.16 15:17:32: ends 2015.06.16 15:17:59', 'lease 129.132.108.235 :starts 2015.06.18 23:12:36: ends 2015.06.18 23:12:35', 'lease 129.132.108.234 :starts 2015.06.19 12:02:01: ends 2015.06.19 12:00:02', 'lease 129.132.108.233 :starts 2015.06.22 06:52:01: ends 2015.06.22 06:46:31', 'lease 129.132.108.232 :starts 2015.06.24 11:40:41: ends 2015.06.24 12:52:26']
```